# Openresty Hello world with docker

Tags: nginx, docker, lua, luajit, openresty

I'm trying make my application dockerize for that I've been following official openresty [dockerfile](https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/blob/master/xenial/Dockerfile). Os in my system is Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

I have already pull that image using this cmd.

```
docker pull openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial
```

Now I want to use this image and want make simple hello world application. For that I have created my work directory, create one custom dockerfile and build my custom image with that. And finaly I run that image. Below is my dockerfile content.

```
FROM openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial

EXPOSE 8080
CMD nginx -p `pwd` -c nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log stderr notice;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 8888;
        location / {
            default_type text/html;
            content_by_lua_file "app.lua";
        }
    }
}
```

**app.lua**

```
ngx.say('Hello World!')
ngx.exit(200)
```

**Build image**

`docker build -t user/openresty .`

**Start container**

```
docker run rahul/openresty
```

When I try to start container, it gives me an error like nginx: invalid option: "/bin/sh"

I have no idea that I'm going on right or wrong direction.

**Update:**

```
docker run -it -p 8888:80 -v /home/software/docker/openresty:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/html:ro openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial
```

I just used this CLI and it's start showing index.html that I have created. Again I tried to link my custom nginx.conf using below CLI but it's not working.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /home/software/docker/openresty:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/html:ro -v /home/software/docker/openresty/nginx.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial
```

docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/app openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial -p /app -c nginx.conf

With below command it starts working but can anyone please explain it?

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/app openresty/openresty:1.11.2.3-xenial -p /app -c nginx.conf
```

Comment: Your nginx listen on 8080 port, but you expose 80 port. First example works because default config listen on 80 port.

Comment: I updated my nginx.conf and second CLI too. Now it's working but now it tries to find app.lua files in "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/app.lua". Instead of that it should look that file in /home/software/docker/openresty/app.lua

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong port settings, look:

EXPOSE 8080
    !=
listen 8888;